# Como ocultar esta etiqueta en Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Ruby on Rails y en la esquina superior izquierda aparece una etiqueta desplegable con información acerca del servidor. ¿Hay alguna manera de eliminarla?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que estás utilizando la gema [rack-mini-profiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler); si no se indica lo contrario, esa etiqueta se muestra únicamente en desarrollo. Te recomiendo revisar la [documentación](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler) de la gema para que puedas configurarla de acuerdo a tus necesidades.

Comment: Gracias, desactivando la gema ahora no aparece!